# Unzipping with zlib in Node.js results in incorrect header error

Tags: node.js, zlib, unzip

In short I'm trying to read a `.zip` file from my file system, deflate the zip-file and them stream it with xml-stream to do some things with the contents in the file.

I thought this would be fairly simple and started with this:

```
var fs        = require('fs')
    , XmlStream = require('xml-stream')
    , zlib = require('zlib');

//- read the file and buffer it.
    var path = '../path/to/some.zip';
    var fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(path, { encoding: 'utf8' });

//- use zlib to unzip it
    zlib.gunzip(fileBuffer, function(err, buffer) {
       if (!err) {
         console.log(buffer.toString());
       }
       console.log(err);
    });
```

But this results in a

```
 { [Error: incorrect header check] errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }
```

Changing the encoding or the method (`.unzip`, `.gunzip` or `.inflate`) isn't working either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use zlib.unzip instead zlib.gunzip

Answer (score 1):

Gzip is not zip. They're different compression formats, just like RAR is. The error indicates that what you're trying to read is not a gzipped file.

You can use a different library, such as [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/).

Comment: Great suggestion!  I needed to read a buffer of a ZIP file retrieved from Amazon S3 and JSZip offered the most straightforward method for doing so...with a simple 'var zip = new JSZip(buffer)'.  I could then iterate through the 'zip.files' object and decide what to do with the files from there.

Comment: I'm using zlib.unzip instead zlib.gunzip

Answer (score 0):

I'm using zlib.unzip instead zlib.gunzip